# How to capture the dichotomy between "Ideal specimen" and an the species?

Tags: culture, fantasy-races, species, races

How to reasonably worldbuild a species that exhibits a set of qualities and principles (has a "hat"), but also *doesn't* view it as an ideal and would view that a perfect/moral specimen steps away from them?

Comment: You seem to essentially be asking if A views itself the same way the B views A. Sometimes and some ways yes, sometimes and some ways no. Do others view you the way you view yourself? Would an elf view you the way you view yourself? Voting to close as primarily opinion based, though I am open to retracting -- there has been a lot of study on this subject..

Comment: Could you specify exactly what your question is? I see several questions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What's exceptional to a human isn't necessarily exceptional (or even necessarily defining) to another species. I think lobsters are ugly and gross, yet male and female lobsters seem to find each other quite attractive. What's human viewpoint got to do with it?

Comment: Just as a note, in future, you might wish to explain your question in clear explicit terms (ie. plain English) rather than in terms of references to games. Many members who could offer you a valuable insight are not game players.

Answer (score 0):

This is really opinion-based. Specifically, an opinion on what is perfect.

Okeer did not aim to create a perfect Krogan, he wanted to make a perfect warrior (from Krogan material). If he wanted a perfect scientist, the result would be very different. And both would be different from perfect parent.

About beautiful elves. So human note that most elves have a trait that they call "beauty". If most members of a group share a trait, it was either evolution or design. If evolution, it must be that elves preferred to mate with somebody who is beautiful (while dwarves preferred stronger/sturdier partners). So evolution scenario does give you elves that actively prefer beauty, so they will be likely to view themselves superior b/c of it.

Even if elves were designed to be beautiful by their creator, there is still an issue of identity. If elves like other elves more than other races, they will like the traits that distinguish them from those other races.

One final note is that "beauty" could be a side effect of being attuned to nature, or being fast and agile and precise. But even then, beauty is something you can see from a distance, while other characteristics are hidden. So elves will still favor beauty.

PS I have read that fantasy/sci-fi races were really created as metaphors for human races/nationalities/sub-cultures. So it is perfectly fine to project inter-human issues into the inter-race relations.

Comment: I am aware it might not have been the case in the Mass Effect 2's story; that's why I wrote that this quote makes it appear that this was the point. That, however, is not really why I'm asking a question - it's because what I had read have led me to some other conclusions. I apologise for being imprecise.